# Jquery Mobile issue with sliding back when im clicking back

Tags: jquery-mobile, hyperlink

I have a great issue with data-transition of a `a` tag. Sometimes when i'm clicking on the a tag it goes with the right transition `back(right to left)`, but sometimes it goes `from left to right`. This is my back button(a tag):

```
<a href="#account" data-direction="reverse" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="arrow-l" data-transition="slide" data-iconpos="notext" data-rel="back"></a>
```

HTML structure:

```
<!-- #account -->
<div data-role="page" id="account">
    <div data-role="panel" id="panel_menu" data-display="reveal"></div>
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <div class="ui-btn-left">
            <a href="#panel_menu" data-display="push" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
        </div>
        <h3>Account</h3>
        <div class="ui-btn-right">
            <a href="" id="logout" data-role="button" data-theme="r">Logout</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content"></div>
</div>
<!-- #shop -->
<div data-role="page" id="shop">
    <div data-role="panel" id="panel_menu" data-display="reveal"></div>
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <div class="ui-btn-left">
            <a href="#panel_menu" data-display="push" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
            <a href="#account" data-direction="reverse" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="arrow-l" data-transition="slide" data-iconpos="notext" data-rel="back"></a>
        </div>
        <h3>Shop</h3>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="false" id="listview_shop"></ul>                
    </div>
</div>
<!-- #shop_details -->
<div data-role="page" id="shop_details">
    <div data-role="panel" id="panel_menu" data-display="reveal"></div>
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <div class="ui-btn-left">
            <a href="#panel_menu" data-display="push" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
            <a href="#shop" data-direction="reverse" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="arrow-l" data-transition="slide" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
        </div>
        <h3>Shop details</h3>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content"></div>
</div>
```

When I'm clicking in the shop_details on the back button it slides in the right way.. But when I'm clicking in the shop on back it slides in the wrong way..

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: it works in firefox but no tin chrome safari etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove attribute **`data-rel="back"`** from this button:

```
<a href="#account" data-direction="reverse" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="arrow-l" data-transition="slide" data-iconpos="notext" data-rel="back"></a>
```

**`data-rel="back"`** will return you to a previous page, in this case it will return you from page **shop** to page **shop_details**.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/mdr3E/

Comment: I don't even use Firefox, I have tested this on Chrome.

Comment: well caching problems.... since a hour i'm testing this and that, I have deleted that data-rel="back" beacause it isn't needed at this point but now it works xD tanks :)

Comment: Then you should open another question. This solution fixed your current problem. I can't see your other sites nor I am psychic.